# extracting value from array in codeigniter

Tags: arrays, codeigniter

When I dump my the varable

```
var_dump($search_results_returned['post_q_2_full']);
```

the following is printed:

```
  array(1) { 
          [0]=> array(7) {
                     ["user_id"]=> string(2) "15" 
                     ["user_name"]=> string(12) "Steve Smith" 
                     ["user_username"]=> string(8) "sjcallan" 
                     ["user_image_filename"]=> string(16) "xhewimg_15.jpeg"     
                     ["user_first_name"]=> string(5) "Steve"
                     ["user_last_name"]=> string(6) "Smith" 
                     ["user_email"]=> string(18) "ssmith@gmail.com" 
          }
    }
```

When I am trying

```
foreach ($post_q_2_full as $post2) { // line 48

echo $post2['user_first_name'];
}
```

## I am getting the following error:

Message: Undefined variable: post_q_2_full

Filename: _account/search.php

## Line Number: 48

And the following error message is thrown at my face as well:

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: _account/search.php

Line Number: 48

I will appreciate any eventual help.

Regards, Zoran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do a foreach loop on a variable that does not exist. 
post_q_2_full is the key inside $search_results_returned variable, and not a variable on it's own.

So what you're looking for is this:

```
 <?php
 foreach ($search_results_returned['post_q_2_full'] as $post2) { // line 48
    echo $post2['user_first_name'];
 }
```

Note:
IMHO the variable name is too long, so I would try to shorten that in the actual production code.

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting the following error:
>   Message: Undefined variable: post_q_2_full

What you `var_dump`-ed: $search_results_returned['post_q_2_full']

What you `foreach`-ed: $post_q_2_full

Get the difference?

> And the following error message is thrown at my face as well:
>
> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

It's the effect of `foreach` above

Comment: You're referring to two DIFFERENT variables